# Problem with Workbook_SheetChange on excel

Tags: excel, vba

My problem is :

This works

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Sheets("Index").ListObjects("TabelaIndex").ListRows(ActiveSheet.Index - 2).Range(Target.Row - 4).Value = Target.Value

End Sub
```

but not this

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)

Sheets("Index").ListObjects("TabelaIndex").ListRows(Sh.Index - 2).Range(Target.Row - 4).Value = Target.Value

End Sub
```

Error :  Subscription out of range

EDIT:

The problem is : when I change the value of another sheet, it triggers Workbook_SheetChange too, so it becames a loop. How do I solve it?

Comment: Think about what should happen if `ActiveSheet.Index <= 2` and respectively `Sh.Index <= 2`. Try adding the line `Debug.Print ActiveSheet.Name, ActiveSheet.Index` and respectively the line `Debug.Print Sh.Name, Sh.Index` before (above) each of the lines and monitor what is happening in the `Immediate` window (`Ctrl + G`). What about `.Range(Target.Row - 4)`? `Range(-1)` may not work.

Comment: @VBasic2008 The same code works in Worksheet_Change, so the problem is not the variables. With this code, I can watch a worksheet for changes, but I wanted to do this with all the sheets at the same time, that's why I put the code in the Workbook

Comment: @Athos Try inserting `Application.EnableEvents = False` before changing the value and `Application.EnableEvents = True` afterwards, this should prevent the triggering of another `Workbook_SheetChange`. see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51986899/worksheet-change-event-stuck-in-infinite-loop/51987020)

Comment: I would also check that sh is not equal to the Index-Sheet. Assumption: Codename of Index-Sheet is wsIndex then you can use: `If wsIndex.name <> sh.name then` plus disabling events